# Java hierarchy inside an android listner

Tags: java, android

In my android application I want to solve the following scenario.

```
class Login extends Activity {
   @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         LayoutBuilder  objLB=new LayoutBuilder(this);
         objLB.createSpinner();
    } 

    public void spinnerItemSelectedEvent(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int pos, long id)
    {
    }
}



class LayoutBuilder {
    private Activity objActivity;

    public LayoutBuilder(Activity a) {
        objActivity = a; 
    }

    public void createSpinner() {
        final Spinner objSPItem = new Spinner(objActivity);
        objSPItem.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id)
                {
                    // Do some common activity 
                    objActivity.spinnerItemSelectedEvent(parent,view,pos,id);
                    // calling this for do some additional task
                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
        });
        objActivity.spinnerItemSelectedEvent()
    }
}
```

and the problem is when i try to access spinnerItemSelectedEvent(parent,view,pos,id) from  the 'onItemSelected' listner inside createSpinner method
 I got the following error.

**The method spinnerItemSelectedListener(AdapterView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type Activity**

but out side the listner the access to the method works ok(neglect parameter list). What is the reason behind that? is any alternate way exist for solving this? plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity in android represents a screen. You are making a variable `objActivity` of type `Activity` whereas it should be of type `Login` where the function `spinnerItemSelectedEvent()` is declared. Change the following lines:

```
private Activity  objActivity;
```

to

```
private Login  objActivity;
```

and your code should run.

**EDIT**

Have a `BaseActivity` and let all your other activities extend this `BaseActivity`. To make the function `spinnerItemSelectedEvent()` reusable declare it in the `BaseActivity` and you can use it the way you are trying to do it now.

Example:

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity{
    public void spinnerItemSelectedEvent(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int pos, long id){ }
} 

  class Login extends BaseActivity{
   public void spinnerItemSelectedEvent(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int pos, long id){ //Local implementation of the function}
}

class LayoutBuilder {
private BaseActivity objActivity;

}
```

Comment: Actually I wrote the LayoutBuilder class for reusing it in all activities, according to your suggestion my code reusablility will lose.

Comment: Thanks Arun. I Solved it according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that inside `LayoutBuilder`, you have declared `objActivity` to be an `Activity`. Declare it to be a `Login` and all should be fine:

```
class LayoutBuilder {
    private Login objActivity;

    public LayoutBuilder(Login a) {
        objActivity = a; 
    }
    . . .
```

EDIT

If you want your `LayoutBuilder` class to be reusable by other activities, then one way to do this is via an interface declaration. For instance:

```
public interface SpinnerSelectionHandler {
    void spinnerItemSelectedEvent(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int pos, long id);
}
```

Then declare `Login` as:

```
public class Login extends Activity implements SpinnerSelectionHandler {
    . . .
```

Finally, redefine `LayoutBuilder` to take a `SpinnerSelectionHandler` in its constructor:

```
class LayoutBuilder {
    private Activity objActivity;
    private SpinnerSelectionHandler selectHandler;

    public LayoutBuilder(Activity a, SpinnerSelectionHandler handler) {
        objActivity = a;
        selectHandler = handler;
    }
```

And then replace

```
objActivity.spinnerItemSelectedEvent(parent,view,pos,id);
```

with

```
spinnerHandler.spinnerItemSelectedEvent(parent,view,pos,id);
```

Plus, if you don't need the `Activity` reference for anything else, you can get rid of it from the `LayoutBuilder` class.

Comment: Or another way is casting `((Login)objActivity).spinnerItemSelectedEvent(parent,view,pos,id);`

Comment: Actually I wrote  the LayoutBuilder class for reusing it in all activities, according to your suggestion my code reusablility will lose